# Winston is only logging .info errors and doesn't log error to file or mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, winston

I am using express-mongoose for my backend and winston as my logger. The problem is that winston is only logging the info messages not errors
The logs in server.log
[image]

Error messages only get logged on console but neither in the file nor mongodb
[image]

the logger code

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

// Import mongodb
require('winston-mongodb');

module.exports = createLogger({

transports:[
//Console transport
    new transports.Console(),

// File transport
    new transports.File({
    filename: 'logs/server.log',
    format:format.combine(
        format.timestamp({format: 'MMM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss'}),
        format.align(),
        format.printf(info => `${info.level}: ${[info.timestamp]}: ${info.message}`),
    )}),

// MongoDB transport
    new transports.MongoDB({
        level: 'error',
        //mongo database connection link
        db : 'mongodb://localhost/logs',
        options: {
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        },
        // A collection to save json formatted logs
        collection: 'edushare_logs',
        format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp(),
        // Convert logs to a json format
        format.json())
    })]
});
```

I created an error by not defining the jwt.
the code

```
const logger = require("./utils/logger")
if (!config.get("jwtPrivateKey")){
    logger.error("FATAL ERROR!! JWT is not defined!")
    process.exit(1)
}
```

Comment: Anyone who can help me please?

Comment: what is the version of `winston`, `winston-mongodb` npms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The winston "console transport" is synchronous, however the processes to write to mongo or file are asynchronous. In this case you can use the winston function callback. Try this:

```
const logger = require("./utils/logger")
if (!config.get("jwtPrivateKey")) {
    logger.error("FATAL ERROR!! JWT is not defined!", () => {
        exit(1);
    });
}
```